# WebSocket file transfer IndexOutOfBoundsException (Buffer overflow)

Tags: javascript, websocket, buffer, netty

Transfering smaller files is possible without any problem, but when I use larger files the socket goes inactive and closes with cause 1006. Netty throws the following exception: https://hastebin.com/paxibawuco.bash (IndexOutOfBoundsException) properly an buffer overflow.
Since I'm using a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` this error should not appear.. It does also work perfectly with a timer of 500ms between every packet sent.

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) {

    ChannelPipeline pipe = channel.pipeline();

    pipe.addLast(ssl.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
    pipe.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
    pipe.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
    pipe.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/websocket"));
    pipe.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64 * 1024, 0, 4, 0, 4));
    pipe.addLast(new FrameDecoder());
    pipe.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
    pipe.addLast(new FrameEncoder());
    pipe.addLast(new ServerHandler());

}
```

Is there any way of transfering the file slices without blocking the thread or sending packets with a delay?